# How can I represent matrix one in mathematics?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a equation such as

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6];
J=ones(size(A));
B=max(A(:))*.J-A;
```

In which $J$ is [matrix of ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones) with its size equal A's size.The above equation show how to compute $B$ from given matrix $A$. It will be find a maximum value of matrix $A$ then multiple it with a matrix one and perform the subtraction with A matrix.

I am looking for a way to represent the relationship between matrix $A$ and $B$ in mathematics. Could you suggest to me a common definition for above equation $(B=max(A(:))*.J-A)$?

Comment: What is that equation? What is it actually saying? Not all of us read Matlab. (`IdentityMatrix` is the identity in Mathematica; `ConstantArray[1, {n, m}]` gives a matrix of 1s.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens: The equation represents the relationship between $B$ and $A$ such as $ (B=max(A(:))∗.J−A)$. This equation only shows the how to calculate B in MATLAB . I would like to find a way to represent it by mathematical

Comment: I updated it to make more clearly question. Let see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: given $A$ an $m \times n$ matrix whose $i, j$th component is $a_{ij}$, let $$\mu = \max \{ a_{ij} : 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$$

Let $J_{m \times n}$ be the $m \times n$ matrix whose $i, j$th component is $1$: that is, the all-ones matrix. (This notation isn't quite standard, but it's as close to standard as I know. $J$ is often the all-ones matrix, but you should always define it before using it.)

Then the Matlab code is finding $$\mu J_{m \times n} - A$$

Comment: What is $I$? For your answer, the ConstantArray[Max[A], {n,m}] - A looks programming code. I expect  simple expression in mathematics.

Comment: $I$ was a typo for $J$. What do you mean by "Mathematical"? I've been assuming, since you've used the words "mathematic", "mathematica", "mathematical", that by all three you meant "Mathematica", which is Wolfram Research's programming language. Did you not mean that?

Comment: Sorry about my english, it is "mathematics"

Comment: Ah. I'll edit my answer to remove the Mathematica bit.

Comment: Yes. that is what I am looking for. However, do you have any simple way to represent matrix of ones in mathematics (with smallest word)

Comment: Not really. "$J$ where $J_{i,j} = 1$" is the shortest I know.

Comment: I tried to find some standard representation for matrix of ones. However, I could not find that

Answer (score 1):

Use the [max norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Max_norm)
$$
 B = \|A\|_{max}\,J-A
$$